# how to find the anchor tag within the anchor tag?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul>
 <li class="topnav">FirstSet
   <ul>
     <li><a href='1.aspx'/></li>
     <li><a href='2.aspx'/></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="topnav">SecondSet
   <ul>
     <li><a href='3.aspx'/></li>
     <li><a href='4.aspx'/></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

this is my menu control, when i am on the 1.aspx/2.aspx i need to hightlight the menu **FirstSet**

```
$("#nav").find("a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']").each(function() {
         $(this).addClass("activeTab");
});
```

using the abouve jquery code, i tried to add the class dynamically. 
Please let me know if i am missing somethignn in the above jquery.

Comment: Well, what happens? And what steps have to done to try and troubleshoot it? :-)

Comment: Try adding some console.log statements. i.e. console.log(window.location.pathname) and see what selector you're generating.

Comment: I am not able to add the class dynamically... I am confused how to write the jquery code to add class for the li, if i have an anchor tag same as window.location.pathname.

Comment: @paul: I am getting the url, i add alert(window.path.location); and its giving the correct url.

Comment: Are you getting the full URL? Or the last item in the path? What exactly do you see?

Comment: @paul:when i am viewing the 1.aspx, i am gettign an alert as 1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `each()` call:

```
$("#nav").find("a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']").addClass("activeTab");
```

Depending on where nav is, you could probably do this:

```
$("#nav a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']").addClass("activeTab");
```

Comment: Handy information. However, if the post doesn't work, then neither will this.

Comment: this isn't working... i tried to get all the anchor tag using $("#nav li.topnav ul li a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']"); but not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add the class to the enclosing `topnav.li`, something like this should work:

```
$('#nav')
  .find('li.topnav')
  .has('a[href='+window.location.pathname+']')
  .addClass('activeTab');
```

This is plain string matching: be aware that something like a leading slash `/` in the `window.location.pathname` but not in your `<a>` tags will cause the match to fail.

Comment: i tried this and its giving the error 
$("#nav").find("li.topnav").has is not a function

Comment: `.has()` was added in jQuery 1.4. What version are you using?

Comment: i guess i am using the version 1.3.. thanks, i will update my version and check this.